# how can i modify the author with git?

Tags: git

After initting a repository , I commit once without configuring name and email .
and then I edit a file in repository and then commit again without configuring name and email.
and now I excute below commands to update name and email :

```
git config --global user.name "name" 
git config --global user.email abc@d.com 
git commit --amend -m "some information"
```

I use git gui to check the modified file , and find the committer is right my name and email . but the author still keep it was like my computer's name@host . How can i let it right . 
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice solution is to use `--reset-author`:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

Another possibility would be an amend with the `--author` option:

```
git commit --amend --author="My Name <my.name@email.com>"
```

---

**Resources:**

- [git-commit manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html)

Comment: this will amend the first time commit's author ?

Comment: This will only fix the latest commit. If there are more than the one commit that need to be fixed, you'll need to look into `git filter-branch`.